# sh: hardhat: command not found when installing Hardhat

Tags: npm, ethereum, npx, hardhat

Trying to build a project with Hardhat, I have node v15.14.0, and ran the following commands:

```
npm init -y

npm install --save-dev hardhat
```

Terminal gives me:

[image]

Then I ran:

```
npx hardhat
```

But got an error saying:

> sh: hardhat: command not found

Comment: So it was because I ran [npx hardhat] in the wrong directory, switching to the right directory solved fo me

Answer (score 3):

You should use NPX.
The Node Package eXecute allows us to directly access and execute a package stored (or not) in `$ ./node_modules/.bin/your-package`.

Using `npx hardhat [GLOBAL OPTIONS] <TASK>` everything will works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install --save-dev hardhat` again did it for me.